# Downloading file using unirest library, Node.js

Tags: node.js, unirest

I am trying to download a file using Node's unirest library. This is my code so far:

```
unirest.get(url).end(function(res) {
            require("fs").writeFile(`${path}/app.zip`, res, "binary", (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
});
```

However, the created zip file is incomplete. I had also tried using pipe, however it's no saving anything. What may be the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

`res` does not contain the response data, for that you need [`res.body` or `res.raw_body`](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-nodejs#response).